# "invalid character 'u' looking for beginning of value"Parsing Error from an Service developed in golang

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am trying to have the response from API which is developed in Golang.
Using PostMan I get the proper response, but when I use [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests) library, I get the following message:

```
{  
    u'status':400,
    u'title':u'Unable to parse data',
    u'code':u'400001',
    u'id':u'edf83LlwYx',
    u'detail':u"invalid character 'u' looking for beginning of value"
}
```

My Python script is:

```
import requests
import json
import data

url = data.user_login

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'content-encoding': 'deflate'
}

form = {
    "username": "askjhashdasjd",
    "password": "asdfASDF1234#="
}

response = requests.post(url,headers=headers, data=form)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
print json_data
```

I am getting the proper response from the other services using this script.

Comment: it's a unicode type character. you could convert that unicode to string using str()

Comment: check the difference between `r.text` and `r.json()`. `r.encoding` is `utf-8`

Answer (score 9):

```
data_to_send = json.dumps(form).encode("utf-8")
response = requests.post(url, data=data_to_send)
```

This Makes the thing done :)