# how to do post request in python with a stored variable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

trying to make post requests in python, i'm getting this error

```
import requests

token='Bearer aslkdjndskgns'

endpoint = "https://aap.xyz"

phone_number='9177903753951'

data = {"number":phone_number}

datas = str(data)

headers={"authorization":token}
a=(requests.post(endpoint, data=datas, headers=headers).json())
```

i'm getting this error

`invalid character 'p' looking for beginning of value "`

Comment: Please refer the below link and see if solution provided resolves your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082081/invalid-character-u-looking-for-beginning-of-valueparsing-error-from-an-serv

Comment: On which line you are getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, see if it resolves your issue.

```
import requests

token='Bearer aslkdjndskgns'

endpoint = 'https://aap.xyz'
data = {'number':'9177903753951'}
headers={"authorization":token}

a=(requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers=headers).json())

print(a)
```